# how to make checkbox selected in codigniter

Tags: php

I am new in  php dont know how to make them selected

here is my code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user_name" value="<?=$user['user_id']?>" >

<input type="checkbox" name="assigned_ids[]" class="check_name"  value="<?=$user['user_id']?>">

<input type="checkbox" name="section_ids[]"  class="check_section" value="<?=$section['section_id']?>">
```

Thia is my code as i was testing weather validation working or not i found an issue as i checked user_name and assigned_id then click on submit button it display a message of username is required so i want how to make them checked

in case of dropdown i use `<?=($this->input->post('month') == 'December')?'selected':''?>` working fine but in checkbox don't know please provide me solution

Comment: <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'December')?'checked':''?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.g if u want make checkbox checked then..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user_name" value="<?=$user['user_id']?>" <?= $user['user_id']!=null && $user['user_id']!=''?"checked=checked":"";?> >
```

change conditions according to u.

Comment: also please  provide me solution as i checked names then it display dropdown of selected name

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Checked' attribute on input tags.

Comment: i used checked before it display all the name comming from database as checked

Comment: The only solution is: your input tags must be constructed at PHP level that is in your backed script which deals with database manipulation.

You just need to integrate into HTML  single php variable to which you assign HTML input tags string. It worked for me and it works for you.

Comment: <?php foreach($sections as $section){ ?>

<ul class="name">
<li>
<label>
<span class="users_check"><input type="checkbox" name="section_ids[]" checked  class="check_section" value="<?=$section['section_id']?>"></span><p><?=$section['section_name']?></p>
     
   </label>
</li>

 <? } ?>

Comment: please tell me how to do it